# Display base64 encoded image in imageview: SWIFT 3

Tags: swift

I have base64 image string which is downloaded from a webpage using POST request and I am trying to decode and display inside imageview but it's not working. I have tried couple of sources but no luck :(

```
let base64String = "data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4aaQSkZJRg0BMADAE15a5df.....H/12Q=="
```

Currently, trying this method:

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacter) {
   let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
   ImageView.image = image
} else {
        print("error in decoding")
  }
```

Tried `NSData` method also:

```
let dataDecode:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: base64String!, options:.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let image= UIImage(data: dataDecode as Data)!
yourImageView.image = image
```

The `else` part always executes. I have tried this in xCode playground by putting encoded string in static variable and noticed `nil` in front of if condition line.

Not sure, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `base64String` is actually a URL with a data scheme. There is built in support for these types of URLs.

You can do something like:

```
let dataString = "data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4aaQSkZJRg0BMADAE15a5df.....H/12Q=="
let dataURL = URL(string: dataString)
let data = Data(contentsOf: dataURL)
let image = UIImage(data: data)
```

I leave it as an exercise to properly handle optional values and error handling.

Comment: thank you, the code seems to work in playground because image width and height is being displayed in front of `let image = UIImage(data: data)` but it's not working in project. :( I'm handling error in `do....catch` block. I have noticed the `do` block is executing because I am printing a message and also printed base64string to see; if it exist in variable. PS: I am using swift soup parser and selecting image source with this selector: `let image = try doc.select(".big-title > img").attr("src")`

Answer (score 1):

be careful, only part of the string represents the image

let base64String = "data:image/jpg;base64,9j/**4aaQSkZJRg0BMADAE15a5df.....H/12Q==**"

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Any tip to extract actual string from URL string?